# tcolorbox is not breaking at the end of the page

Tags: tcolorbox

I started to prove a theorem using 'proof' environment thusly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\begin{document}   
\begin{tcolourbox}   
   text  
\begin{proof}  
\begin{enumerate}[i.]  
    text  
\end{enumerate}  
\end{proof}  
\end{tcolorbox}   
\end{document}
```

But the proof is so long that the box crosses the page number (footer) but does not move on the next page just like
[image: this]

Comment: Please make sure the example shows the problematic behavior. Hint the `kantlipsum` packages provides `\kant` which supplies sample English text

Comment: You might also want to fix the typo in the environment name. The environment is called `tcolorbox` without the additional "u".

Comment: Notice the end of the image where text is overlapping the page number 10

Comment: Additionally, please make sure your example even compiles.

Comment: @leandriis that was a typo.

Comment: Probably, you want to use `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]` in combination with `\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}` in order to get a colored box that automatically breaks across pages.

Comment: @leandriis problem solved.. thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is soled by comments.

Answer (score 0):

`\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` supports automatic breaking of tcolorbox.
See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox.

Comment: Did you actually try it? `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` is not enough. See leandris' comment to the quesiton.

Comment: I confess, no. It is hoped that reference to the manual will give our questioner enough guidance to find a solution to their problem